# MySQL: When adding a WHERE, the position is always 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wrote a SQL query that outputs a list of clan ids and their positions.

```
SET @n := 0;

SELECT id, @n := @n + 1 AS position
FROM (
    SELECT clans.id, SUM(clans_members.xp) AS xps
    FROM clans
    INNER JOIN clans_members ON clans_members.clans_id = clans.id
    GROUP BY clans.id
    ORDER BY xps DESC
) AS s;
```

Result:

[image: Result SQL]

But if I add WHERE id = 6 (as seen in the previous screenshot, the position of the clan with id 6 is 3), it outputs this result:

[image: Result with WHERE]

Even if I specify any other id, it will still output position 1. What to do and how to fix it?

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @FanoFN 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL v8, you can do something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT clans.id, SUM(clans_members.xp) AS xps, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(clans_members.xp) DESC) RowNum
    FROM clans
    INNER JOIN clans_members ON clans_members.clans_id = clans.id
    GROUP BY clans.id
    ORDER BY xps DESC)
SELECT id, RowNum
FROM cte
WHERE id=6;
```

Use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to generate row number on your original query, wrap that in a [common table expression(cte)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions) then filter the `id=6`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sM1uOW5j)

Comment: NICE!!! IT WORKED! Even ChatGPT couldn't help me, although it gave me many different fixes... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE` clause in your case.

```
SELECT 
     clans.id, SUM(clans_members.xp) AS xsp, (@n := @n + 1) AS position
FROM clans
     INNER JOIN clans_members ON clans_members.clans_id = clans.id 
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) param
GROUP BY clans.id
HAVING clans.id = 6
ORDER BY xsp DESC;
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, maybe that's the error, that one entry is output, but applying your code, I still get position 1

Comment: Which MySQL version that are you using? And please add some sample data for your `clans` and `clans_members` tables to your question.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check. Hope it could help.

Comment: 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.10.1